# If rank($J_f(x))=n$, then there exists a neighborhood such that for each of its points $y$, $rank(J_f(y))\geq n$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^p$ be a $C^1$ function defined on an open subset $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^q$. If for some $x \in U$, the jacobi matrix $J_f(x)$ has $rank$ equal to $n$, then there exists an open neighborhood $V$ of $x$ for each $x \in V$, the jacobi matrix $J_f(y)$ has rank at least $n$.

My approach:

I do not really have an approach.
I know that for a matrix $A$, $rank(A):= \dim im(A)$. What also comes to mind is that $rank(A)=n$, would mean that $A$ has $n$ linearly independent columns. If I would have to guess, I would say it has something to do with the $C^1$, i.e. $J_f$ is continuous. And somehow using the continuity the result should follow. But I don't know how to approach this. Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: the function
$$A\longmapsto\hbox{square submatrix of }A\longmapsto\det(\hbox{square submatrix of }A)$$
is continuous.

Comment: I did some thinking, could it be that the solution is a result from the implicit function theorem?

Comment: @Peter, how? Using what implicitly defined function? Your original idea is easy and it works.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up some theorems, that was why I suddenly thought of the implicit function theorem.

So by what your hint was:
If $J_f(x)$ has rank $n$, then consider the determinant of the $n \times n$ submatrix A(x). Since $det(A(x)) \neq 0$ and all operations were continuous, one can conclude that there exists a neighborhood $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^q$ such that for $y \in V$, $det(A(y)) \neq 0 $, since the submatrix A was an $n \times n$ matrix, we know that rank of $J_f(y)$ has to be at least $n$.
Does this work?

Comment: @Peter, your proof is finished.